# Launch app on voice command android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

i need an example of app launch on particular word. i know this is possible using speech recognition api. I just need a clue to start.

I see other apps are able to establish this.

Answer (score 0):

I did this b4 using android service.i kept a background service working and added a listiner to it and keep checking the tresults if it equals ur voice command.

Comment: which listener you added can you please help me in that

Comment: In my case i used accelometer sensor ,but In ur case u have to implement RecognitionListener  and keep checking results .

Answer (score 0):

try to use Android Service which listens to voice + voice to text and you can go through the text and find the check word